# How can I mock Identityuser in order that signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) returns true

Tags: authentication, testing, razor, mocking, razor-pages

I'm mocking my repos like this:

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddScoped<ITextPostRepository, TestTextPostRepository>(serviceProvider =>
                    {
                        return new TestTextPostRepository(textPosts);
                    });
                    services.AddScoped<ITagRepository, TestTagRepository>(serviceProvider =>
                    {
                        return new TestTagRepository(tags);
                    });
                    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();
                });
            })
                .CreateClient();
```

but I want to know how can I mock also IdentityUser in order that this

> signInManager.IsSignedIn(User)

from this

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager
```

in my Razor view returns **true**.
It is for testing the displaying of my page when user is connected.

.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userStoreMock = new Mock<IUserStore<IdentityUser>>();
            var contextAccessorMock = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var claimsFactoryMock = new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>>();
            var userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<IdentityUser>>(userStoreMock.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            var signInManagerMock = new Mock<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>(userManagerMock.Object, contextAccessorMock.Object, claimsFactoryMock.Object, null, null, null, null);
            signInManagerMock.Setup(s => s.IsSignedIn(It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>())).Returns(true);

            var client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddScoped<ITextPostRepository, TestTextPostRepository>(serviceProvider =>
                    {
                        return new TestTextPostRepository(textPosts);
                    });
                    services.AddScoped<ITagRepository, TestTagRepository>(serviceProvider =>
                    {
                        return new TestTagRepository(tags);
                    });
                    services.AddScoped<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>(_ => signInManagerMock.Object);
                });
            })
                .CreateClient();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**